# Paradigm for handling list of things or single elements

Tags: python, weak-typing

Very often when coding in Python (or any language where type is not specified) I run into the following problem:

I want to write a function that can accept either a thing, or a container of such things in general. For example consider this subset function:

```
def subset(df, months=all_months):
    return df[pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Timestamp']).month.isin(months)]
```

I would now like to be able to call this both with a list of months, or a single month. The second case however is only possible by something ugly like:

```
subset(df, months=["June"]) # Why not just subset(df, "June")?
```

I can think of 2 solutions, neither of which feels elegant to me:

- I can use `isinstance` and treat scalars different that containers.
  This is not the best because I type check and also there are cases where the code in the function is complex and needs major revision when treating scalar instead of list
- I could cast the argument to list: `months = [months]`. Again I would be using the `isinstance` though.

Is there are better looking solution than the ones I thought of? Even better, is there a well known solution that I am not aware of?

**EDIT**

Both answers provided acceptable solutions. I decided to stick with the one proposed by @Doc Brown because I can easily isolate the type checking into a decorator and want to avoid introducing unwrapping into the API for workplace specific reasons.

Comment: This is the classical *Composite design pattern*. By searching for that term and "Python" you will find different ways of implementing it.

Comment: @KilianFoth: I don't think this applies here. "Composite design pattern" would require to wrap the passed parameter in an additional class hierarchy, but additional wrappers is exactly what the OP tries to avoid. Moreover, in Python one can already use a list or a scalar in exchange when calling a function, that is syntactically ok.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an argument list:

```
def subset(df, *months):
    for month in months: ...

subset(df, 1)
subset(df, 1, 2)
subset(df, *[1, 2])
```

It's easiest for users of your api to understand how things work when functions work in exactly one way. Behaving differently depending on what you're passed can be very confusing.

Comment: I really like this solution with the exception of the 3rd call. I work in a field where I do not expect the majority of my coworkers to be familiar with unwrapping.

Comment: I'd put some effort into developer education. Features built into the language shouldn't be surprising to anyone working with it professionally.

Comment: It took me some time but I finally decided to accept your answer. I am now using this method and include a link to the docs for unpacking in the docstring. Thanks :)

Comment: That's a good idea!

Answer (score 2):

Using type checks (for example, by utilizing `isinstance`) can be a sensible solution (even [the implementation of the `isin`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/indexes/datetimelike.py#L736-L755) function you used for demonstration purposes makes use of it). In a language with dynamic typing like Python, there is no function overloading like in statically typed languages. So often the cleanest and simplest approach to distinguish between different kinds of parameters is indeed to use `isinstance`, especially when you want to solve a problem in a generic manner.

However, one has to be careful not to detect strings here as sequences (which are sequences of characters). You only want "a sequence of strings" or a single "string" as valid. Given you want to support built-in collections (or strings) as input, you can do the requires type check with a helper function like this one:

```
def makeSequence(obj):
    if type(obj) in [list, tuple, xrange]:
        return obj
    else:
        return [obj]
```

So with this implementation

```
def subset(df, months=all_months):
    months=makeSequence(months)
    # ... maybe some complex code dealing with a collection of months ...
    return df[pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Timestamp']).month.isin(months)]
```

the code does not need *"major revision when treating scalar instead of list"*, it is a simple, straightforward change to the function which just adds one line at the beginning, and leaves the already existing code untouched.

Note further that the "bad reputation" of functions like `isinstance` or the kind of type checking above is probably caused by cases where type checking is abused in a manner which violates the Open-Closed principle. When, for example, `isinstance` is called for a list of different types, maybe from a class hierarchy, with special case handling for each type, new requirements often lead to a necessity of not forgetting to extend that list. In such a situation the usage of `isinstance` becomes error-prone and should be avoided. However, the use case above is not exactly the same: for this use case, `makeSequence` most probably needs only to support the built-in collections of Python, so nothing which will change very frequently.

Once you have a basic layer of such functions which works on scalars and lists as well, other functions based on that layer do not need to implement such special treatment any more. So maybe you can try to implement such a layer?

Comment: I see your point about using `isisntance` in this context and I think I agree.
Since these situation appear often in my application I decided to extend your solution by writing a decorator (which does the check you mentioned and delegates to the function call with a list argument.

Comment: `isinstance("abc", Sequence) == True` so if a single month is a string, this implementation does exactly the wrong thing. It's much simpler to do *one* thing. Easier to test, easier for people to remember how to use. Add in a type annotation as well and then tooling can give you extra assistance.

Comment: @Daenyth: thanks for your comment, missed that, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply rely on English grammar:

```
def subset(df, *, months=None, month=None):
    if months is None:
        if month is None:
            raise ValueError('subset must be called with either month= or months= parameter')
        else:
            months = [month]

    return df[pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Timestamp']).month.isin(months)]
```